# Django check session without creating it in datebase

Tags: python, django, session

I usually check the session like this:

```
if request.session.get('var', False):  
  ...
```

The only problem, that if I do that and the session does not exist, django creates it - adds a row to django_session table.
How can I perform this check without creating the session if it does not exist?

Comment: Does setting [`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) to `False` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And as you can see, this setting is False at default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions backends handle sessions in a get-or-create fashion by default. Given that you're using the database backend, you can wrap the access in a `atomic` statement, to automatically rollback if no data was found:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        var = request.session['var']
except KeyError:
    var = False
```

**EDIT**:

If you can't get that to work (though I'm curious why that wouldn't work), you can try the following to access the session data without triggering the `_get_session` method:

```
try:
    var = request.session._session_cache['var']
except AttributeError:
    try:
        s = Session.objects.get(
            session_key=self.session_key,
            expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
        )
        request.session._session_cache = self.decode(s.session_data)
        var = request.session._session_cache['var']
    except (Session.DoesNotExist, SuspicousOperation, KeyError):
        var = False
except KeyError
    var = False
```

The Django `SessionStore` object (accessible through request.session) implement the dictionary interface and makes use of internal caching. All normal dictionary access makes use of the `_session` property, which tries to access the internal cache, and if that fails, creates a new session object and stores it in the database. By directy accessing the internal cache (`session._session_cache`), you skip the property, and if it fails, the session backend doesn't automatically create a new session. This is just what Django does internally, without creating a new session object when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Does not work for me. And, isn't this method will still save to the database and then restore? Can I just check the session without creating it at all?

Comment: If you remove the try/except, does it raise a `KeyError`? The backend itself creates the session if there is no session and you try to access it. You can create your own backend with a custom `load` method.

Comment: Yes, it does raise KeyError. And, when that happen, the rollback is indeed working as expected- no data is saved in database.  But, if I "catch" the exception, a new row is still created in the database

Comment: And just to be clear, this is my code:      `try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            request.session['userID']
    except:
        pass
    return render(request, 'index.html', {} )`

Comment: Couldn't do breakline. Just wanted to point out that I didn't make the mistake of catching exception inside atomic block. I did it as mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Comment: Ok, I don't know why it won't work, but I've added another solution that should work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! could you just explain what is the difference between accessing the sesssion in this way and the regular way ? is this method has any flaws? I couldn't find any info. Though this problem is now solved, I now have a different problem regardless the session, why I am calling request.session.delete(), and it still doesn't delete from database.

Comment: @user3599803 Check my edit. My former code wouldn't  load any session data if the session object wasn't loaded and cached already. You should probably ask your problem with `delete()` in a new question.